# TouchID / FingerprintScanner React-Native

Tags: react-native, fingerprint, expo, touch-id

I want to add TouchID / FingerprintScanner support to an app that I'm developing with React-Native@0.54+ and all packages that I use I cannot link the dependencies to it via react-native link  (or even without package-name...).

I'm running it via 'create-react-native-app' and using Expo Client.

Any thoughts / help?

Answer (score 1):

i think you shoud detach expo.

working with Expo gives you lots of benefit... but deeper you want to achieve, Expo will make you struggle.

I suggest you to deatch Expo and work with libraries like

https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id
or
https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner

Answer (score 1):

Its worth pointing out that Expo supports fingerprint scanning with their LocalAuthentication module. There's an example snack available in their [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/sdk/local-authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

there is quite a good example [here](https://medium.com/react-native-training/integrate-touch-id-and-face-id-to-your-react-native-app-707e7db17edc) so have a look. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expo's fingerprint reader library in ejected apps too. I explained it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64929151/7477198

Or it is possible to use libraries like https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner#readme