# How to check support of Touch ID, Face Id ,Password and pattern lock in React-Native

Tags: react-native, touch-id, face-id, passcode, android-biometric

I am using `react-native-fingerprint-scanner` for **Touch ID, Face Id, Passcode** authentication.

**Touch ID** is working for me but How can I check if device support or not?

I have tried using `react-native-touch-id` but it is not for `Face Id` on android.

**Is there any way to achieve this for both platforms (iOS/Android)?**

Reference:[Link](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can see if the device is supported by a module. What's the problem?

Comment: How to check in react-native any lib?

Comment: The answer to that has already been written by Johnborges.

Comment: for me `biometryType` returns `true` only and how to go for `pattern/password`

Comment: Is the value of 'biometryType' always true, not a string?

Comment: on my device I have set all three pattern it returns `true`

Comment: have you fixed it for face id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-native-touch-id` should work for both TouchID and FaceID.

> iOS allows the device to fall back to using the passcode, if faceid/touch is not available. this does not mean that if touchid/faceid fails the first few times it will revert to passcode, rather that if the former are not enrolled, then it will use the passcode.

[from the docs](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id#methods)

You can check to see if its supported first.

```
const optionalConfigObject = {
  fallbackLabel: 'Show Passcode', 
  passcodeFallback: true,
}

TouchID.isSupported(optionalConfigObject)
  .then(biometryType => {
    // Success code
    if (biometryType === 'FaceID') {
        console.log('FaceID is supported.');
    } else {
        console.log('TouchID is supported.');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Failure code
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Have you done for pass code if finger scan not done

Comment: From my understanding, thats not how the pass code fallback works. See my updated answer.

Comment: react-native-touch-id is a deprecated plugin, which one can I use today?

Comment: It doesn't look deprecated just not actively maintained. An alternative is `expo-local-authentication`

Comment: @johnborges do you have implementation guide for this `expo-local-authentication`?

Comment: you can use my guide where i have puted code, if touch id or face ID fails than you can use device passcode https://github.com/avaiyakapil/react-native-touch-id

Answer (score 3):

`react-native-touch-id` supports FaceId too. But, is not actively maintained anymore. So, they recommend to use expo local authentication. It works in all react native applications regardless of expo or not.

To use this, first you have to install `react-native-unimodules`. follow this guide https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/

Once it is installed you can install it by

```
npm install expo-local-authentication
```

add following line to your import

`import LocalAuthentication from 'expo-local-authentication';`

After that, we can use it.

```js
async function biometricAuth(){
  const compatible = await LocalAuthentication.hasHardwareAsync();
  if (compatible) {
    const hasRecords = await LocalAuthentication.isEnrolledAsync();
    if (hasRecords) {
      const result = await LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync();
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

It will automatically choose between available local authentication (TouchID, FaceID, Number lock, Pattern lock etc) and authenticate the user.

Comment: Yes, it is for react native. Expo team made it supported for RN. Follow the steps above.

Comment: "import * as LocalAuthentication from 'expo-local-authentication'; " should be right here.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for android devices which supports only face recognition unlock. Do you know any solution? 
I provided precise question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73391435/face-id-biometry-face-recognition-unlock-on-android-devices-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGQl4.png)
// use this package import RNBiometrics from "react-native-simple-biometrics"; this is both for touchId and passcode for android and ios

Comment: Please consider sharing the code directly in the answer instead of in a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-touch-id` will work for both TouchID and FaceID

> I have updated the repo so now if you want to use passcode after face ID or Touch ID fails than use will be prompted to enter the PIN (only for ios)checkout my repo

https://github.com/avaiyakapil/react-native-touch-id

```
import TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id';

TouchID.authenticate('Authentication')
     .then(success => {
              // Success code
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Failure code
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//this code is for checking whether touch id is supported or not
    TouchID.isSupported()
          .then(biometryType => {
            // Success code
            if (biometryType === 'FaceID') {
              console.log('FaceID is supported.');
            } else if (biometryType === 'TouchID'){
              console.log('TouchID is supported.');
            } else if (biometryType === true) {
              // Touch ID is supported on Android
        }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // Failure code if the user's device does not have touchID or faceID enabled
            console.log(error);
          });
```