# Face Id, biometry, face recognition unlock on Android devices in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, face-recognition, biometrics, face-id

Currently I'm using `expo-local-authentication` and it works properly when Android device has touch id / fingerprint unlock possible also. Normal behaviour is when fingerprint is added and face registered then user can decide which biometry option wants to use but anyway  `supportedAuthenticationTypesAsync()` returns only array with
`AuthenticationType.FINGERPRINT`, but not see `AuthenticationType.FACIAL_RECOGNITION`.
In this case when fingerprints are not saved in phone then face recognition works properly.
The problem happens when android device doesn't have fingerprint hardware, but supports face recognition. Then it's not detected by library and this option doesn't work.
I also tried `react-native-biometrics` and result was the same.

TLDR:

**Is there any other solution for Android in React Native that supports face recognition unlock on Android devices?**

**Or what's is the reason why it's not working in that libraries right now?**